# Alterar linhas de código dentro de arquivos com Apache Ant

Tags: apache, ant

Estou estudando o Apache Ant para tentar realizar a alteração de algumas linhas de código existentes dentro de arquivos, porém até o momento não encontrei nada a respeito na documentação oficial o maximo que consigo é renomear arquivos como este exemplo

```
<move todir="my/src/dir" includeemptydirs="false">
<fileset dir="my/src/dir"/>
<mapper type="glob" from="*.default.properties" to="*.local.properties"/>
```

Queria saber se já passaram por isso e como posso resolver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar outros recursos executáveis do OS e gerar uma `task`.

No seu caso, você poderia criar uma `ant task` usando `sed`.

Uma outra opção é o [replaceregexp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html)

Exemplo:

```
<replaceregexp byline="true">
  <regexp pattern="OldProperty=(.*)"/>
  <substitution expression="NewProperty=\1"/>
  <fileset dir=".">
    <include name="*.properties"/>
  </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

Comment: era isso mesmo que eu precisava, usando o oldproperty e new property consigo perfeitamente reslver meu problema.

Comment: Ótimo. Acho que esta pergunta precisa de tags melhores, por isso iniciei outra pergunta no Meta, em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1784/qual-a-tag-apropriada-para-uma-pergunta-relacionada-a-tasks-ants

Comment: Eu tentei coloca-lás porém não tenho reputação para isso ainda.

Comment: Agora ficou bom. :D